# Update code comments on git commit

Tags: php, git

I have a file called `VERSION.md` in my project root directory.

On commiting my changes, I want the classes to change the code comments for the following automatically.

1. `@date`
2. `@version`
3. `@since`

All my comments follow `PhpDoc2`.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a git hook (a way to execute some arbitrary code on certain events, before committing, for example).

There are plenty of articles/tutorial about them in the web.
See, for example, [here](http://githooks.com).